# What does "SMP PREEMPT RT" mean in `uname -a`?

Tags: linux-kernel

As per the subject, here is the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux 4.19.82 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Mon Mar 2 17:33:16 PST 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

There is no related information in `man uname` indeed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

“SMP” means that the kernel was built with support for SMP (symmetric multi-processing).

“PREEMPT” means that the kernel was built as a [preemptible kernel](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.7.1/source/kernel/Kconfig.preempt#L38).

“RT”, on version 4.19, means that the kernel was built as a fully preemptible (real-time) kernel, using [the Preempt RT](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/start) patches.

The string you see in `uname -a`’s output is constructed by [`scripts/mkcompile_h`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/mkcompile_h) based on the kernel’s build configuration options.